# Converting text to file and save it to in a folder

Tags: php

I have been trying to save input contact as a file in a folder but i don't know how to go about this using php.

```
<php
if(isset($_POST['s'])){
$neexe = $_POST['nameextention'];
$filecont = $_POST['fileBody'];

$folderpath = 'Files';
// I wan to save this as page.php with the body content inside so users can download it

}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="nameextention" value="page.php"/>
<textarea name="fileBody"><?php if(isset($_HELP['please'])){echo 'i really need to get this done!!';}?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="s" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: you want to save test to textfile ya pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. use **fopen** built-in function as below:

```
$myfile = fopen($neexe, "w") or die("Failed to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $filecont);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Oh this is so fun, very simple code to do thank, please what about folder path?

Comment: Please indicate the folder path to save my new file @Ratul Doley

Comment: prepend it to the file name `$fileDirectory.$neexe`. If you do not specify a path it will be written in the same directory as your script

Comment: If ur folder name is 'myfolder' then just modify the line as : $myfile = fopen("myfolder/".$neexe, "w") or die("Failed to open file!");